# How to drop symbols from a list of titles?

Tags: r, regex

I have the following list of titles:

```
cols = c("to_test.namespace.(1,Inf]","to_test.namespace.(1,20]","from_test.namespace.(1,200]")
```

I need to drop `(` and `]`.

If I apply this piece of code, it only works for `to_test.namespace.(1,Inf]`, but does not do anything for the rest.

```
out <-  sub("\\.?\\((\\d+),\\s*([A-Za-z]+)\\]$", "_\\1_\\2", cols)
```

I need to get the following result:

```
cols = c("to_test.namespace.1_Inf","to_test.namespace.1_20","from_test.namespace.1_200")
```

or:

```
cols = c("to_test.namespace_1_Inf","to_test.namespace_1_20","from_test.namespace_1_200")
```

Both options are fine.

How can I do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use

```
sub("\\.\\(([^,]+),([^[]+)\\]", "_\\1_\\2", cols)
#[1] "to_test.namespace_1_Inf"   "to_test.namespace_1_20"    "from_test.namespace_1_200"
```

Comment: Thanks, but as far as I see, it does not drop commas. I get `to_test.namespace1,Inf`

Answer (score 0):

You could add matching digits 0-9 to the character class.

```
\.?\((\d+),\s*([A-Za-z0-9]+)\]$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PRQBfs/1)

In the replacement use the leading dot or underscore

```
.\\1_\\2
```

For example

```
sub("\\.?\\((\\d+),\\s*([A-Za-z0-9]+)\\]$", ".\\1_\\2", cols)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
gsub("\\((.*),(.*)\\]","\\1_\\2",cols)
[1] "to_test.namespace.1_Inf"   "to_test.namespace.1_20"    "from_test.namespace.1_200"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option

```
sub(",", "_", gsub("\\(|\\]", "", cols))
#> [1] "to_test.namespace.1_Inf"   "to_test.namespace.1_20"   
#> [3] "from_test.namespace.1_200"
```